# Ubuntu 20 on Active Directory -- wrong user and group IDs assigned

Tags: permissions, active-directory

I'm trying to join my Ubuntu 20 virtual machine to our Active Directory setup. Everything seems to be working, except the user IDs shown for users do not match what is in Active Directory. This means that (among other problems) users cannot access their home directories which are served/mounted from another server.

The user ID for rgoodman should be as shown here (from the non-working machine):

```
$ ls -ld /home/rgoodman
drwxr-xr-x 70 1101210 1100513 12288 Feb 23  2019 /home/rgoodman
```

On a working server (which is actually running CentOS), I see this:

```
$ id rgoodman
uid=1101210(rgoodman) gid=1100513(domain users) groups=1100513(domain users),1101210(rgoodman),1110778(customer-support-sg),1110770(cacti-sg),1110867(software-development-sg),1110838(phoenix-dev-sg),1000001(BUILTIN\users)
```

On my server which isn't working, I see this:

```
$ id rgoodman
uid=945201210(rgoodman) gid=945200513(domain users) groups=945200513(domain users),945210867(software-development-sg),945210838(phoenix-dev-sg),945210778(customer-support-sg),945210770(cacti-sg)
```

It's interesting that the end of each number is the same, but the prefix is different. How do I change the prefix on this machine to match what is in AD? Is the BUILTIN\users at the end of the working machine's list a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using SSSD to integrate with Active Directory.  My guess is that the configuration of SSSD is simply different between your CentOS and Ubuntu servers.

The "end of each number" almost certainly corresponds to the **RID** in Active Directory.  This will generally get added to the range of a "slice" in SSSD.  This is confusing, but fairly well documented: [Ubuntu Manpage: sssd-ad - SSSD Active Directory provider - id mapping](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/sssd-ad.5.html#id%20mapping).

You say "the user IDs ... do not match what is in Active Directory".  Are you actually defining uids in Active Directory or do you really mean they do not match the CentOS server?  If you are defining the values in AD, e.g. using the `uidNumber` attribute for uid, then you can update your `sssd.conf` to disable the automatic id-mapping.  The config would be something like:

```
ldap_id_mapping = False
ldap_schema = ad
```

If you want to keep the automatic mapping that I believe is happening, a potential fix is to set your AD domain as the default domain.  The default domain gets mapped to slice 0.  This can help keep the id-mapping consistent with other setups:

```
ldap_idmap_default_domain_sid = S-1-5-21-blahblahblah
```

You can set the `debug_level` to a high value and the logs should fairly clearly indicate how the uid is being generated.

If you change the id-mapping settings in SSSD, be sure to clear out the SSSD cache *completely* before testing again:

```
systemctl stop sssd
rm /var/lib/sss/{db,mc}/*
sss_cache -E
# optionally clear debug logs
truncate -s 0 /var/log/sssd/*.log
systemctl start sssd
```

You've given no information on how the various systems are joined to AD so other tools may also be in play. For example, Samba can be used to integrate with AD and uses its own id-mapping options.

Comment: The configuration file for these changes is /etc/sssd/sssd.conf ? Sorry I'm working sort of blind here, trying to clean up a setup that I didn't do.

Comment: Yes. `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`